# Как сделать генератор случайных чисел, выдающий одинаковые значения при нескольких запусках?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Посоветуйте, как сделать псевдослучайный генератор, иницилизирующийся числом, с помощью которого можно сгенерировать последовательность чисел (несколько тысяч чисел от 0 до 9). Основная задача чтобы при запуске этого же генератора с таким же числом инициализации он выдавал те же самые значения.

Comment: Тоже интересно, нужная штука

Comment: Бррр.. числа-числа-числа состоят.. из цифр!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший вариант:

```
var num; // очень большое простое число.  
var seed; // затравка - то самое инициализирующее число.  
var start_number; // основа  
var counts = new Array();  
var max_num = 10; // Инт, который не превосходит наше число. У вас 0-9 числа.  
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){  
 counts[i] = (Math.pow(start_number+i,seed)%num)%max_num;  
}
```

Механизм простой: возводим основу, изменяемую каунтером в степень затравки и берем остаток от деления на большое число.
Потом берем последние несколько цифр(в нашем случае - одну).

Как можно оптимизировать: бинарное возведение в степень(пользуясь тем, что у нас кольцо)
Замечания:
1) num должен быть достаточно большим, чтобы обеспечить разнообразие.
2) число в степени затравки должно, тем не менее, превосходить это простое число.
3) от основы можно отказаться вовсе, если счет инкрементора начинать с 2, а seed взять, хотя бы, от ~20

Comment: А если без степеней и корней? Возможно только со сложением и логическими операциями?

Comment: Если хочется все же реализовать самостоятельно, степень легко синтезируется из сложений, а поиск остатка - из вычитаний. =Ъ
Более простой метод, боюсь, повлечет за собой гораздо более предсказуемую и менее равномерную последовательность.

Comment: Ваш вариант хорош - 20000 чисел генерятся без повторов и задержки! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

И ведь не надоедает людям изобретать не то что велосипеды, но даже лапти...

[Линейный конгруэнтный метод](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос успешно обсуждался на оригинальном SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s